# implicit declaration in libreoffice basic

Tags: basic, libreoffice-basic

I've tried the example code [here](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Working_With_Variables) (`a = b + c`). Suprisingly, the reality is not the expected behavior.

With Win7 and LO 4.4.2.2, I see `a` and `b` are declarated as integers whose values are 0, and `c` is empty.

With Ubuntu 16.04 and LO 5.1.6.2, they are all empty.

Any idea how to explain the first case ?

Comment: With LO 4.4.3.2 on Linux Mint, they are all empty, so I am not able to reproduce your results.

Answer (score 1):

From https://help.libreoffice.org/Basic/Using_Variables:

> As soon as the variable has been declared, it is automatically set to the "Null" value. Numeric variables are automatically assigned the value "0" as soon as they are declared.

As the link in the question seems to suggest, implicit *initialization* is bad programming practice in Basic.  So strange results should not be surprising when using old versions.

With Perl,  `$a = $b + $c;` sets the value of $a to zero because it is a mathematical result, and $b and $c are initialized to an empty string.  Perl has a long history of facilitating undeclared variables, although nowadays `use strict` is recommended.